# What is the purpose and use of the `EnumerableExecutor` class?

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, ienumerable, expression

Here is the documentation for [System.Linq.EnumerableExecutor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerableexecutor.aspx).

I can't figure out what it could possibly do or be used for.  Below is the source code I get from reflector:

```
public abstract class EnumerableExecutor
{
    [TargetedPatchingOptOut("Performance critical to inline this type of method across NGen image boundaries")]
    protected EnumerableExecutor(){}
}

public class EnumerableExecutor<T> : EnumerableExecutor
{
    [TargetedPatchingOptOut("Performance critical to inline this type of method across NGen image boundaries")]
    public EnumerableExecutor(Expression expression){}
}
```

Any takers?

Comment: " _This API supports the .NET Framework infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code._ "

Comment: not sure anyone here is going to be able to offer more than "Represents an expression tree and provides functionality to execute the expression tree after rewriting it", to be honest, but you never know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is stated in the documentation, it is not intended to be used by our code. It has internal methods that might be useful to the internals of the Framework, such as:

```
internal T Execute();

internal override object ExecuteBoxed();
```

It seems that the purpose is to provide functionality to compile an `Expression`, execute it and return the result.